# How to use IfElse function with character variables

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to create dummy variables with R and my code is not working. I would like to change the auction location to 1 if it is Hong Kong and to 0 if it is not. By applying the code below all the values become 1 and not only the one corresponding to Hong-Kong.

Here is the code I applied:

```r
Database$HGK=ifelse(Database$Auction_location>="Hong-Kong",1,0)
```

Can you help me to find the solution?

Comment: `Hong-Kong` is a string, which can't be used to compare its value with Auction_location  (so <= is not valid). What if `Database$Auction_location == "Hong-Kong"`

Comment: I think you meant to use `==` instead of `>=`. Your current code runs without error because strings actually can be compared using "greater than" and "less than" operators, based on alphabetical ordering (i.e., `'b' > 'a'` is true, `'a' > 'b'` is false).

Comment: Thanks ! Do you know how I could modify my code so that Hong-Kong is taken into account and replaced by 1 or 0?

Comment: `Database$HGK=ifelse(Database$Auction_location == "Hong-Kong",1,0)` should work.

Comment: Try `Database$HGK <- as.integer(Database$Auction_location == "Hong-Kong")` or the slower but case-insensitive `Database$HGK <- as.integer(grepl("Hong-Kong", Database$Auction_location, ignore.case = TRUE))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `==` operator, here an `tidyverse` approach

```
library(dplyr)

Database %>%
  mutate(HGK = if_else(Auction_location == "Hong-Kong",1,0))
```